# Scala: Print separators when using output stream

Tags: scala

When we need an array of strings to be concatenated, we can use mkString method:

```
val concatenatedString = listOfString.mkString
```

However, when we have a very long list of string, getting concatenated string may not be a good choice. In this case, It would be more appropriated to print out to an output **stream** directly, Writing it to output stream is simple:

```
listOfString.foreach(outstream.write _)
```

However, I don't know a neat way to append separators. One thing I tried is looping with an index:

```
var i = 0
for(str <- listOfString) {
  if(i != 0) outstream.write ", "
  outstream.write str
  i += 1
}
```

This works, but it is too wordy. Although I can make a function encapsules the code above, I want to know whether Scala API already has a function do the same thing or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self Answer**:

I wrote a function encapsulates the code in the original question:

```
implicit def withSeparator[S >: String](seq: Seq[S]) = new {
  def withSeparator(write: S => Any, sep: String = ",") = {
    var i = 0
    for (str <- seq) {
      if (i != 0) write(sep)
      write(str)
      i += 1
    }
    seq
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
listOfString.withSeparator(print _)
```

The separator can also be assigned:

```
listOfString.withSeparator(print _, ",\n")
```

Thank you for everyone answered me. What I wanted to use is a concise and not too slow representation. The implicit function withSeparator looks like the thing I wanted. So I accept my own answer for this question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that do what you want in a bit more elegant way:

```
def commaSeparated(list: List[String]): Unit = list match {
    case List() => 
    case List(a) => print(a)
    case h::t => print(h + ", ")
                 commaSeparated(t)
}
```

The recursion avoids mutable variables.

To make it even more functional style, you can pass in the function that you want to use on each item, that is:

```
def commaSeparated(list: List[String], func: String=>Unit): Unit = list match {
    case List() => 
    case List(a) => func(a)
    case h::t => func(h + ", ")
                 commaSeparated(t, func)
}
```

And then call it by:

```
commaSeparated(mylist, oustream.write _)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is the overloaded definitions of `mkString`.

Definitions of `mkString`:

```
scala> val strList = List("hello", "world", "this", "is", "bob")
strList: List[String] = List(hello, world, this, is, bob)
```

`def mkString: String`

```
scala> strList.mkString
res0: String = helloworldthisisbob
```

`def mkString(sep: String): String`

```
scala> strList.mkString(", ")
res1: String = hello, world, this, is, bob
```

`def mkString(start: String, sep: String, end: String): String`

```
scala> strList.mkString("START", ", ", "END")
res2: String = STARThello, world, this, is, bobEND
```

*EDIT*
How about this?

```
scala> strList.view.map(_ + ", ").foreach(print) // or .iterator.map
hello, world, this, is, bob,
```

Comment: also, sometimes, it's usefull to use `mkString(firstDel, del, lastDel)`

Comment: No, What I want to do is write to output stream directly, not getting concatenated string, because I have very long list to be concatenated.

Comment: Edited, is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you, but tailing additional comma "," makes problem for some context.

Comment: Yes, it is what I did in original question. What I want to ask is out-of-the-box function to do this in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Not good for parallelized code, but otherwise:

```
val it = listOfString.iterator
it.foreach{x => print(x); if (it.hasNext) print(' ')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which avoids the var

```
listOfString.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (s, i) =>
    if (i != 0) outstream write ","
    outstream write s }
```